# linking weapon to 3ds max automatically scales it for some reason

Tags: animation, 3dsmax

I am new to 3ds max and I am trying to link a weapon to the hands of my character, I am using link constraint but whenever I try to link it to the hands, the weapon suddenly gets scaled way up, and the weapon is rotated for some reason.

[Before linking](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DNtto.png)

[after, check the scale](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LjXWj.png)

[after, check rotation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HTCVE.png)

Answer (score 0):

I would try to [reset XForm](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/3ds-max/learn-explore/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2020/ENU/3DSMax-Basics/files/GUID-B98414B9-4F28-45F4-A1F4-9DA994548ED9-htm.html) - that is likely the problem.